# transfer data between activities

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

How would I go about transferring some data between two activities?

my 1st activity takes current time

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and my second activity contains a little sum with the startTime

```
long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
```

Comment: See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting second activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putLong("startTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

Reading the value in the second activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
long value = b.getLong("startTime", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between activities by using the extras in an Intent object.  When you create your intent, simply do a:

```
myIntent.put("startTime", startTime);
```

and in your other activity, do a:

```
intent.getIntExtra("startTime", 0);
```